# Web workers inside a JS library with Rollup

Tags: javascript, webpack, rollup

I am building a negamax engine in Typescript that uses Thread.js web-workers. It is a npm library that will be imported by an application built using webpack.

I am using Rollup to build the engine - how can I export the web-worker files so they are copied into the client's build directory as a separate chunk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plugins for that: [Alorel/rollup-plugin-web-worker](https://github.com/Alorel/rollup-plugin-web-worker), [darionco/rollup-plugin-web-worker-loader](https://github.com/darionco/rollup-plugin-web-worker-loader)

..but I ended up doing it by scratch, using a separate build configuration for the worker(s). This simply gives me more control over the situation.

Attached is the `rollup.config.worker.js` that I use.

The main `rollup.config.mjs` imports this file, has its configuration as the first build configuration. The real build config uses `@rollup/plugin-replace` to inject the worker's hash to the code loading it.

```
/*
* Rollup config for building web worker(s)
*
* Imported by the main rollup config.
*/
import sizes from '@atomico/rollup-plugin-sizes'
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace'
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser'

import {dirname} from 'path'
import {fileURLToPath} from 'url'

const myPath = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

const watch = process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

const REGION = process.env.REGION;
if (!REGION) throw new Error("'REGION' env.var. not provided");

let loggingAdapterProxyHash;

const catchHashPlugin = {
  name: 'my-plugin',

  // Below, one can define hooks for various stages of the build.
  //
  generateBundle(_ /*options*/, bundle) {
    Object.keys(bundle).forEach( fileName => {
      // filename: "proxy.worker-520aaa52.js"
      //
      const [_,c1] = fileName.match(/^proxy.worker-([a-f0-9]+)\.js$/) || [];
      if (c1) {
        loggingAdapterProxyHash = c1;
        return;
      }
      console.warn("Unexpected bundle generated:", fileName);
    });
  }
};

const pluginsWorker = [
  resolve({
    mainFields: ["esm2017", "module"],
    modulesOnly: true       // "inspect resolved files to assert that they are ES2015 modules"
  }),
  replace({
    'env.REGION': JSON.stringify(REGION),
    //
    preventAssignment: true   // to mitigate a console warning (Rollup 2.44.0); remove with 2.45?
  }),
  //!watch && terser(),
  catchHashPlugin,

  !watch && sizes(),
];

const configWorker = {
  input: './adapters/logging/proxy.worker.js',
  output: {
    dir: myPath + '/out/worker',   // under which 'proxy.worker-{hash}.js' (including imports, tree-shaken-not-stirred)
    format: 'es',   // "required"
    entryFileNames: '[name]-[hash].js',   // .."chunks created from entry points"; default is: '[name].js'

    sourcemap: true,   // have source map even for production
  },

  plugins: pluginsWorker
}

export default configWorker;
export { loggingAdapterProxyHash }
```

Using in main config:

```
  replace({
    'env.PROXY_WORKER_HASH': () => {
      const hash= loggingAdapterProxyHash;
      assert(hash, "Worker hash not available, yet!");
      return JSON.stringify(hash);
    },
    //
    preventAssignment: true   // to mitigate a console warning (Rollup 2.44.0); remove with 2.45?
  }),
```

..and in the Worker-loading code:

```
const PROXY_WORKER_HASH = env.PROXY_WORKER_HASH;    // injected by Rollup build

...
new Worker(`/workers/proxy.worker-${PROXY_WORKER_HASH}.js?...`);
```

If anyone wants to get a link to the whole repo, leave a message and I'll post it there. It's still in flux.

---

**Edit:**

After writing the answer I came across this: [Building module web workers for cross browser compatibility with rollup](https://justinribeiro.com/chronicle/2020/07/17/building-module-web-workers-for-cross-browser-compatibility-with-rollup/) (blog, Jul 2020)

TL;DR If you wish to use EcmaScript Modules for the worker, watch out! Firefox and Safari don't have the support, as of today. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker) And the `Worker` constructor needs to be told that the worker source is ESM.